# Problem with mime type while rendering html file from node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mime-types

I am using node.js webserver. I am also socket.io and webrtc for getting audio streaming in my application. I am rendering a html file from here using a path /audio as shown here.

```
const webServer = http.createServer(app);

const socketIo = require("socket.io")(webServer); // web socket external module

app.use( '/assets', express.static( path.join( __dirname, 'assets' ) ) );

// Rendering html file
app.get( '/audio', ( req, res ) => {

res.sendFile( __dirname + '/index.html' );
} );
```

The html file contains CSS and js files an I am loading them as below.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href='assets/css/app.css' type="text/css">
<script type="module" src='./assets/js/rtc.js'></script>
<script type="module" src='./assets/js/events.js'></script>
<script type="module" src='./assets/js/autolink.js'></script>
```

When I am running this html file through /audio, I am unable to load these CSS and JS files. In the console I am getting this mime type error.

[image: Console errors]

I have tried all the solutions that I have got through web. But nothing worked as of now.

Comment: Go to the inspector network tab and check the response of error requests to make sure the contents responded by server properly.

Comment: I am not able to see the response in the network tab for particular request. But when I go to the path through browser, I am able to fetch the data in CSS file.

Comment: You need to figure out why you can’t see the response in the network tab. You **should** be able to and you need to know why it is returning an HTML content-type. Since you claim it works when you go directly to the URL, odds are that you are dealing with different URLs (and the one the doesn’t work isn’t the same as the one you are testing).

Comment: Can you share the complete node.js server code. I don't see any problem with your code.

Answer (score -1):

Try to setting the header contentType in the response for every your css and javascript files like this below

res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/css');    /// for every  css files

res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/javascript');   // for js files

Comment: How? The static middleware is built into express. It doesn’t lend itself to being edited … and should be giving the correct Content-Type headers anyway

Comment: Ok  I  never used static in my express apps sorry, but reading docs https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html  you make mistakes putting '/assets' in paths of your script tags,  try to omit it,  For examples:   <script type="module" src='./js/rtc.js'></script> and so on for others links paths, without '/assets'

Comment: They don't appear to have made a mistake there. `app.use( '/assets'` — `/assets` in the route they are mounting the middleware on.